# partly caching a view method

Tags: django, caching, memcached

I am using [Memcached](http://memcached.org/) (with [python-memcached](ftp://ftp.tummy.com/pub/python-memcached/) binding) with one of my django projects. The scenario is that on the homepage i have:

- A Top Bar : *(This contains the links to login / User name with a link to the profile)*
- A Search Form
- Few Blocks Of Results

Currently, I am using the [`cache_page()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs#the-per-view-cache) decorator to cache the whole page as follows:

```
@cache_page(3600)
def home(request):
    # View Code Goes Here
```

and the above is working as expected. But as the homepage is a publicly accessible page i am facing a problem with one scenario where:

1. An anonymous user request the home page(the page get's cached if it
   is not already).
2. Now the user logs in and is redirected to the homepage.
3. The cached homepage loads (Topbar still shows a login link instead of the logged in user's Name and profile link as the page was cached before the user logged in.)

#### Question:

Is there a way either on template level or on view level, that lets us specify a block we **DO NOT** want to cache while using `cache_page()` decorator ?

*Please Note: I am aware that we can use `{% cache %}` template tag or `cache.set` for each block in the above scenario. But i am specifically looking for a solution where we can use the `cache_page()` decorator and still be able to specify a `block` that i do not want cached in a particular view or a template*

Answer (score 0):

use [CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ANONYMOUS_ONLY](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ANONYMOUS_ONLY)

yet it sounds as a middleware option, it affects @cache_page as well